# In Objective C/Swift what do return within a method when an error is thrown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, swift

Note: I say Objective C/Swift in the title of this post because I believe the answer to this question will apply to both languages, but the code I include in this post is Swift.

Java has a nice mechanism for Exception handling, but in Objective C we're either getting an error back from a delegate method or passing an error into a function by reference and then checking it afterwards. I'm wondering, what is the cleanest way to return from a method which expects a return value (such as an NSString, UIImage, or some other complex object) when an error is thrown? I don't know if "thrown" is the correct word to use in Objective C, but I really just mean when you make a call that returns a non-nil NSError.

For example, say I have this code which is trying to create a UIImage of a QR code:

```
func createQRImageWithString(string: String, andWidth width: Int32, andHeight height: Int32) -> UIImage {
    var error : NSError?
    let writer : ZXMultiFormatWriter = ZXMultiFormatWriter()
    let result = writer.encode(string, format: kBarcodeFormatQRCode, width: width, height: height, error: &error)
    if (error) {
        println(error!.localizedDescription)

    } else {
        let image :CGImageRef = ZXImage(matrix: result).cgimage
        return UIImage(CGImage: image)
    }
}
```

This func does not compile because in the if statement no UIImage object is returned. The func creates a contract between the func and anyone who uses it, promising that a UIImage will be returned. In the event of an error, I have no UIImage to return. I guess I could make a dummy empty UIImage and return it, but that's certainly not what is expected. So what is the best way to handle this?

I gave an example using UIImage, but I'd like the answer to be generalizable to any situation where a method promises to return an object, but due to an unforeseen error returning that object is not going to go as planned.

Comment: Out of interest, what would you have done in Java? Or if Swift _did_ have exception handling?

Comment: In Objective-C one does not test the `NSError` out variable to determine if an error occurred, it is not guaranteed to be 0 if there is no  error. Instead test the method for an error and if there is an error then get the error details from the out error variable. This applies to Swift when it calls Objective-C APIs.

Comment: Objective-C does have exceptions but reserves them for programming errors, not program control. Since Swift calls Objective-C APIs the same rules basically apply. The issue is that the Objective-C exceptions are not guaranteed to handle exceptions across stack frames.

Comment: @Zaph by "test the method for an error" do you mean that instead of passing "error" to the if statement, I should pass the return value of the method (which in this case is "result")?

Comment: In Objective-C generally (see specific docs) if there is an error the method will return `nil`. That indicates an error has occurred. Then get the error information from the out error parameter. The out error parameter is not used to indicate an error (there are a few exceptions, again reward the docs on the method) and may be modified by the meths even if there is no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In swift you can use the optional type and return a `UIImage?`, which allows you to either return a `UIImage` or `nil`.

The client will be statically enforced by the compiler to handle the optional return value, so this is a safe approach, as opposed to simply return `nil` (i.e. a `NULL` pointer) in Objective-C.

Comment: Brilliant, when I'm able I'll accept this as the answer. Swift's Optional's make a lot more sense to me now. Do you know if this use-case of Optionals is the main purpose behind them. Are they Apple's version of Exception Handling?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if they are the _main_ purpose behind them, but it does force one to think about invalid values in a coherent and planned way...

Comment: Optional data types are fairly pervasive in functional languages (see Haskell `Maybe` type or Scala `Option` type) and yes, along with others mechanisms they are preferred to exception handling for regular data flows. Keep in mind that Optionals alone are not enough for handling an error, for instance you don't know what caused the error. In other languages we have other constructs for this situations (like a `Try[T]` in Scala), but in swift you'll be probably using the classical Cocoa pattern of taking an out parameter of type `NSError`, to be filled with the appropriate error.

Comment: For more advanced error handling to include the "why", Swift offers enums with associated data (which is a very powerful tool, also common in functional languages). See http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/error-handling-in-swift for a good introduction. But Optional is definitely the answer for simple cases.

Comment: @RobNapier nice reference. The `Return` enum defined in the article precisely mimics the functionality of a `Try` in Scala and that's what I was talking about. Generally speaking exceptions should only be thrown in case of error that neither we nor the client can predict and handle (i.e. unrecoverable situations such as out of memory exceptions, hardware failures and so on). For any other cases using a type representing a failed computation is most likely a better choice.

Comment: Though Scala's `Try` is a bit more complicated since it actually wraps Java exceptions. But conceptually they can be used the same (and I hope that a similar mechanism becomes standard in Swift).

Comment: (I've opened some radars asking the Swift team to spend more time digging through the Scala library for inspiration. :D But in fairness, Scala didn't get Try until 2.10, right?)

Comment: In swift, if you want to return both a possible result and a possible error, just return the tuple `(ResultType?, NSError?)`

Comment: @RobNapier yes, that's why I used 'mimics'. `Try` is also a monadic abstraction in Scala, which makes it definitely more powerful than a plain tagged union. And yes, we got it in 2.10 :)

Comment: @David returning a tuple is a bad idea. You want to return either one of the two and never both together. A tagged union (an typed enumeration in swift) is definitely a better fit.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella The typed enumeration would be a better idea if Swift and/or Xcode actually supported generic enumerations, but right now it crashes on `enum ResultWithError<T> { case Success(T);case Error(String); }`  It also assumes that you never have a situation where it is valid to return a result and an error.  All told, it's probably a better idea if it gets fixed.

Comment: @David well yes, it assumes that situation by definition (it's a union). I didn't know enumerations are buggy, and I definitely hope they get fixed.

Comment: @Gabriele Petronella By plain tagged union, are you just referring to the pass-by-reference NSError? If not, what is a plain tagged union.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union
In this case an hypothetical `ReturnType` could be either a `UIImage` or an `NSError`. `Optional<T>` is a tagged union that can either be `T` or `nil`

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C, throwing exceptions is reserved for programming errors (with very few exceptions). Swift doesn't have exceptions. The Swift designers seem to have decided that while having exceptions seemed to be a good idea, it actually isn't. (And there is plenty of Java code with atrocious exception handling).

If an error happens, your function should return a result that indicates that an error happened, and set an error variable to the description of the error. If your function calls another function that returns an error, then you need to decide whether the error of the function called indicates that your function returns an error or not. For example, a function checking whether WiFi is available or not may call a function that produces an error if there is no WiFi, in which case your function will return that there is no WiFi - without suggesting there is an error.

If the error in the called function means your function fails itself, then the same rules apply: Return a result that indicates there is an error, and set an error variable. In Objective-C, methods often return YES for success and NO for failure, or nil for failure and not-nil for success. In Swift, you usually return an optional value.

Answer (score 1):

One answer is to return a `UIImage?` rather than a `UIImage`, returning `nil` if you have no image to return. Your calling code then has to determine what to do if you have no image. If it is possible that there is no image, then `UIImage` is probably not the right 'contract' to have with your calling code, whereas `UIImage?` is.

Comment: same question as posed to @Gabriele Petronnela